# (EC2) Launch Windows instance programmatically via command line

Tags: ssh, automation, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'd like to launch a Windows 2008 (64bits, base install) instance programmatically, kinda like clicking on the **Launch Instance** link & following the "Create a New Instance" wizard.

I read about this command **ec2-run-instances**, I tried running it on putty using this syntax:

> **/opt/aws/bin/ec2-run-instances** ami_id ami-e5784391 -n 1
>   --availability-zone eu-west-1a --region eu-west-1 --instance-type m1.small --private-key /full/path/MyPrivateKey.pem --group MyRDP

but it always complain that:

```
Required option '-C, --cert CERT' missing (-h for usage)
```

According to the documentation, this option isn't required!!

**Can someone tell me what's wrong anyway?** I'm just trying to programmatically launch a fresh Windows install, run some tests on the clouds & shut it down after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is correct (just try adding `--cert` ;) - to what documentation are you referring here?

The requirement is clearly outlined in the [Microsoft Windows Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Welcome.html?r=8691) for [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), specifically in [Task 4: Set the EC2_PRIVATE_KEY and EC2_CERT Environment Variables](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/InstallEC2CommandLineTools.html#set-aws-credentials):

> The command line tools **need access to an X.509 certificate and a
>   corresponding private key that are associated with your account**. [...]
>
> You can either specify your credentials with the --private-key and
>   --cert parameters every time you issue a command or you can create environment variables that point to the credential files on your local
>   system. **If the environment variables are properly configured, you can
>   omit the parameters when you issue a command**.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Maybe the option of using environment variables has been misleading somehow somewhere?

### Alternative

Please note that you can ease and speed up working with EC2 considerably by using alternate scripting environments covering the same ground, in particular the excellent [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto), which *is a Python package that provides interfaces to Amazon Web Services*.

Boto uses the nowadays more common authentication scheme based on access keys only rather than X.509 certificates (e.g. an AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID / AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY pair), which furthermore can (and should) be managed via [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) to avoid the risk of exposing your main AWS account credentials in the first place. See my answer to [How to download an EC2 X.509 certificate with an IAM User account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995926) for more details on this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! My apologies, I should have been more explicit: I'm trying to launch a Windows instance **from** an Amazon Linux AMI instance, so I used [this guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html). I took a look at the **Example Request** section at the bottom (no certificate is used), I didn't realize env. variables were used.